# Stylesheet for nested custom widget not applied

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qtstylesheets

I expect the following code to show a small black area inside outer main window:

```
class Canvas(QWidget):
    pass

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
outer = QWidget()
w = Canvas(outer)
w.setStyleSheet("background-color: black")
outer.show()
```

But looks like the stylesheet is not applied: entire outer window is gray.
However, if `w` is a `QWidget`, code works as expected. When `Canvas` instance is shown directly (without parent) stylesheet is properly applied as well:

```
w = Canvas()
w.setStyleSheet("background-color: black")
w.show()
```

This code shows a black window.
I have tried same in C++ with Qt 4.8.6 and stylesheet is also properly applied for nested widgets derived from QWidget.

What am I missing?
I am using python 2.7.6, Qt 4.8.6 and PyQt 4.10.4 under Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `QWidget` subclass will ignore stylesheets by default (for performance reasons).

Try this:

```
w = Canvas(outer)
w.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_StyledBackground)
w.setStyleSheet("background-color: black")
```