# Unexpected padding on wrapped QLabel in custom class

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, padding

I want to display a border around a QWidget that wraps a QLabel (this is practice for a more complicated widget). I'm using setStyleSheet to create the border. When I did this manually, it worked as expected. However, when I moved the code into its own class (derived from QWidget), the padding is different, and I can't figure out why.

[image: Output of code example]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout 

class WrappedLabel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text=''):
        super().__init__()

        self.text = QLabel(text)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.text)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setStyleSheet('padding: 2px; border: 2px solid red;')


class Shell(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):  # constructor
        super().__init__()  # call the parent's constructor

        w = QWidget() # Create the main window content widget
        self.setCentralWidget(w)

        # First label
        unwrapped_label = QLabel('This is a normal QLabel with a border and no padding.')
        unwrapped_label.setStyleSheet('border: 2px solid gray; padding: 2px;')

        # Second label
        wrapped_label = QLabel('This QLabel is manually wrapped in a styled QWidget. ' + 
            'There is a slight indent compared to the normal QLabel due to padding.')
        wrapped_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        wrapped_layout.addWidget(wrapped_label)
        manual_wrapper = QWidget()
        manual_wrapper.setObjectName('wrapper')
        manual_wrapper.setLayout(wrapped_layout)
        self.setStyleSheet('QWidget#wrapper { border: 2px solid gray; padding: 2px; }')

        # Third label
        derived_wrapper = WrappedLabel('This class derives from QWidget and wraps a QLabel like above, but is indented even further and the border is in the wrong spot.')

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(unwrapped_label)
        vbox.addWidget(manual_wrapper)
        vbox.addWidget(derived_wrapper)
        vbox.addStretch(1) # Squish them together to better see the spacing

        w.setLayout(vbox)

        # Setup the rest of the main window appearance
        self.setGeometry(300,300,640,180)
        self.setWindowTitle('Testing wrapped labels')

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    shell = Shell() # create and show the main window
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with, the code in the custom class `WrappedLabel` is not exactly the same as for the manual widget. For the manual widget you make sure that the stylesheet is only applied to the widget itself, but not to any child widgets via `QWidget#wrapper`. For you custom class you simply apply the stylesheet to the `WrappedLabel` instance which will cause it to [cascade](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html) to all its child widgets (and also to the `QLabel` instance). This is why your `QLabel` instance ends up with the padding and the red border.

So why doesn't the same happen for the wrapper? Apparently custom base classes of `QWidget`s reject all applied style sheets by default (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29505269/3767239)). You can make this work by adding `self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_StyledBackground)` in `WrappedLabel.__init__`. Now you'll see that you end up with two borders, one for the wrapper and one for the label. To restrict the stylesheet to the wrapper you need to apply a similar identifier as for the manual widget: `self.setStyleSheet('WrappedLabel { padding: 2px; border: 2px solid red; }')`.

So to make it work you can add this to `WrappedLabel.__init__`:

```
self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_StyledBackground)
self.setStyleSheet('WrappedLabel { padding: 2px; border: 2px solid red; }')
```